# How to search for cells by formatting?

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I'm trying to find all cells with bold text in them.  I tried

```
xlApp.FindFormat.Font.Bold = true;
```

before searching using the `Worksheet.UsedRange.Find` method (with the SearchFormat parameter as true), but got a lot of seemingly random cells which I could not get the text of, since they were empty.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is now, it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you want to find cells that are formatted bold and contain text, which means you need to use "*" as your search text instead of leaving it empty, which looks for bold formatted cells.